# Software to export data in sql statement?

Tags: data-migration

Is there any open source software that allows you to export data from tables of (any type of) database to SQL statements?

I know that SQL server's management studio has this as built-in function, and TOAD for Oracle. I was wondering if there are any "generic" software that can do that for a variety of databases, much like the ETL tools (e.g. Talend Open studio)

Comment: From what Database? To what database? Different vendors can have slightly different SQL... failing that - it wouldn't take that long to write a SQL statement to do it for you...

Comment: what I want is any arbitrary "From" and "To" database, that's the point.
For the "To" database, I would like to choose to output "generic/standard" SQL/INSERT statement, I believe most of the databases do accept "standard" SQL statements, especially statements as simple as INSERT statements

Comment: I asked From where and To, because I was going try and help find a open-source app for you, I understand it's arbitrary, but not everyone does everything.